# Intermittent sound on an Medion Akoya S5610

Tags: sound, laptop, intel, alsa, hda-intel

The sound on my machine (Medion Akoya S5610) works intermittently.  If I reboot enough times I do get sound. This happened before I upgraded, when running Oneiric too. I have fiddled around with `alsa-base.conf`, putting in different values for `model` in `options snd-hda-intel model=`but still the issue persists (although I get the impression that I am more like to have sound on the next reboot if I have edited that file although I can't be sure of this). Adding `index=0` does not help the situation either.

I have been thinking that this problem could be related some how to the order that driver modules are loaded. The `snd-hda-intel` module is also used for the sound card (ALC888) in my graphics card. Could it be that these are some how competing? If so, how do I add a preference when they are using the same module?

This is the result of `lspci -nn | grep Audio` (when sound was not working):

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 03)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV620 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 3400 Series] [1002:aa28]
```

I've been wrestling with this problem for ages and ages and have spent days looking for answers on forums but to no avail so I would appreciate any help you can give.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my kernel up to 3.2.0-26 and now everything works correctly all the time, even after hibernation.

I do have the line `options snd-hda-intel model=auto` in my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file.

Hope this helps